# RETURN construct Format in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My query is

```
START n=node(*) return count(n)AS `Number of nodes is`;
```

The above query will return the answer in a tabluar format.

```
+----------------------------------+
| Total Number of Nodes Populated: |
+----------------------------------+
| 24                               |
+----------------------------------+
1 row
```

How would I go about specifying the format of the return construct. lets say in this concern I want just the answer as '24' or as a JSON.

Comment: Do you want to change the layout of the response in neo4j-shell? Because the real response when calling a remote instance does not have a tabular format, it has the data (`24`) and some metadata (the column name).

Comment: I am trying that on my eclipse env. Yes, its printing in the console. But, I would like to use the result as an object to do further processing. Any pointers in this direction?

Comment: Use the driver in your language of choice to call the Neo4j instance, and process the response however you want.